# Keeping UWP apps updated, but hiding/hiding store app

Tags: windows-10, windows-store, uwp

So I'm upgrading a clients system to Windows 10, and per their request removing as many UWP apps as possible. 
I got stuck on the Windows Store app though, I want to keep it to keep the bare minimum apps I am keeping up to date(calculator, groove, etc). 
But at the same time I don't want the users to be able to see or access the store app. The client also didn't want to run their own store, aka no Microsoft Store for Business. Unless there's a way to use that like a sort of WSUS?

So what's the best way to keep the apps updated, but at the same time hide/disable the store app for the users?

Comment: You cannot achieve both of your goals.  You cannot both receive updates for applications installed through the Windows Store and disable access to the Windows Store by uninstalling it.  You can configure the system to not allow users to install new applications or you can allow the Administrator to push the updates to the applications themselves.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your response! Well I'm fine with leaving in installed as long as users aren't allowed to access it. Are you talking about the GPO to disable the store? And in what way can I set it up so that their admins can manually update the apps? I'm assuming the Windows Store still needs to be installed for that to work though.

Comment: Without knowing specifics about your AD domain I am unable to answer those questions.  How you prevent additional UWP applications from being installed by users is well documented though.  However, and answer that provided specifics on how to do that, wouldn't answer the question you asked.

Comment: @Ramhound Well what does the Admin approved GPO thing have to do with the AD setup? I can probably find info about blocking the store, so thanks for that at least.